# Passing a pointer to a struct in cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm attempting to write a cython interface to the complex version of the MUMPS solver (zmumps).  I'm running into some problems as I have no previous experience with either C or cython.  Following the example of the [pymumps package](https://github.com/bfroehle/pymumps) I was able to get the real version of the code (dmumps) to work.

I believe that my problem are the pointers to the ZMUMPS_COMPLEX structures.  For the

So far I have the following (lifted heavily from [pymumps](https://github.com/bfroehle/pymumps)):

**zmumps_c.pxd:**

```
from libc.string cimport strncpy

cdef extern from "mumps_c_types.h":

    ctypedef struct ZMUMPS_COMPLEX "ZMUMPS_COMPLEX":
        double   r
        double   i

cdef extern from "zmumps_c.h":

    ctypedef int MUMPS_INT

    ctypedef struct c_ZMUMPS_STRUC_C "ZMUMPS_STRUC_C":
        MUMPS_INT      sym, par, job
        MUMPS_INT      comm_fortran    # Fortran communicator 
        MUMPS_INT      n

        # Assembled entry
        MUMPS_INT      nz
        MUMPS_INT      *irn
        MUMPS_INT      *jcn
        ZMUMPS_COMPLEX *a

        # RHS and statistics 
        ZMUMPS_COMPLEX *rhs
        MUMPS_INT      infog[40]

    void c_zmumps_c "zmumps_c" (c_ZMUMPS_STRUC_C *)
```

**zmumps_c.pyx**

```
cdef class ZMUMPS_STRUC_C:
    cdef c_ZMUMPS_STRUC_C ob

    property sym:
        def __get__(self): return self.ob.sym
        def __set__(self, value): self.ob.sym = value
    property par:
        def __get__(self): return self.ob.par
        def __set__(self, value): self.ob.par = value
    property job:
        def __get__(self): return self.ob.job
        def __set__(self, value): self.ob.job = value
    property comm_fortran:
        def __get__(self): return self.ob.comm_fortran
        def __set__(self, value): self.ob.comm_fortran = value
    property n:
        def __get__(self): return self.ob.n
        def __set__(self, value): self.ob.n = value
    property nz:
        def __get__(self): return self.ob.nz
        def __set__(self, value): self.ob.nz = value
    property irn:
        def __get__(self): return <long> self.ob.irn
        def __set__(self, long value): self.ob.irn = <MUMPS_INT*> value
    property jcn:
        def __get__(self): return <long> self.ob.jcn
        def __set__(self, long value): self.ob.jcn = <MUMPS_INT*> value
    property a:
        def __get__(self): return <long> self.ob.a
        def __set__(self, long value): self.ob.a = <ZMUMPS_COMPLEX*> value
    property rhs:
        def __get__(self): return <long> self.ob.rhs
        def __set__(self, long value): self.ob.rhs = <ZMUMPS_COMPLEX*> value

    property infog:
        def __get__(self):
            cdef MUMPS_INT[:] view = self.ob.infog
            return view


def zmumps_c(ZMUMPS_STRUC_C s not None):
    c_zmumps_c(&s.ob)
```

In my python code I'm able to set the irn and jcn using

```
import zmumps_c
import numpy as np

MUMPS_STRUC_C = staticmethod(zmumps_c.ZMUMPS_STRUC_C)
id = MUMPS_STRUC_C()
x = np.r_[1:10]
id.irn = x.__array_interface__['data'][0]
```

However, I have no idea how to set the values of a or rhs.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

> The following example lets you get at the C-level members of Python’s built-in “complex” object:

```
cdef extern from "complexobject.h":

    struct Py_complex:
        double real
        double imag

    ctypedef class __builtin__.complex [object PyComplexObject]:
        cdef Py_complex cval

# A function which uses the above type
def spam(complex c):
    print "Real:", c.cval.real
    print "Imag:", c.cval.imag
```

Grabbed from [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/extension_types.html#external).

As `ZMUMPS_COMPLEX` and the builtin `Py_complex` structs have exactly the same structure, you should be able to do the trick by creating a bridge between those two types (using typedefs and/or cast or a function that turns a Py_complex into a ZMUMPS_COMPLEX)...

I'd love to help more but I don't currently have mumps installed...

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to achieve this - here's one approach.

The code below defines a wrapper for `ZMUMPS_COMPLEX`. It then defines a wrapper for `ZMUMPS_STRUC_C`, with `__get__` and `__set__` methods for the `rhs` property that allow it to accept the `ZMUMPS_COMPLEX` wrapper.

**zmumps_c.pyx**

```
cdef class ZMUMPS_COMPLEX:
    '''A wrapper for the ZMUMPS_COMPLEX struct'''
    cdef c_ZMUMPS_COMPLEX c_zm

    def __init__(self, double real, double imag=0):
        self.c_zm.r = real
        self.c_zm.i = imag

    property r:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.c_zm.r
        def __set__(self, value):
            self.c_zm.r = value

    property i:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.c_zm.i
        def __set__(self, value):
            self.c_zm.i = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({real}{imag:+}j)'.format(real=self.c_zm.r, imag=self.c_zm.i)

cdef class ZMUMPS_STRUC_C:
    '''A wrapper for the ZMUMPS_STRUC_C struct'''
    cdef c_ZMUMPS_STRUC_C ob
    cdef object _rhs

    property rhs:
        def __get__(self):
            return self._rhs
        def __set__(self, ZMUMPS_COMPLEX c):
            self._rhs = c
            self.ob.rhs = &c.c_zm

    def test(self):
        return (self.ob.rhs[0].r, self.ob.rhs[0].i,)

def main():
    z = ZMUMPS_STRUC_C()
    c = ZMUMPS_COMPLEX(-3.5, 2.0)
    z.rhs = c
    print z.rhs
    print z.test()
    c.r = 42.0
    print z.rhs
    z.rhs.i = -5.0
    print z.rhs
```

The `main()` function demonstrates the behaviour of the two objects. The output should look like this:

```
(-3.5+2.0j)
(-3.5, 2.0)
(42.0+2.0j)
(42.0-5.0j)
```

I don't have the library installed, so I tested this using the dummy definitions below:

**zmumps_c.pxd**

```
cdef struct c_ZMUMPS_COMPLEX "ZMUMPS_COMPLEX":
    double r
    double i

cdef struct c_ZMUMPS_STRUC_C "ZMUMPS_STRUC_C":
    c_ZMUMPS_COMPLEX *rhs
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("example.pyx")
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is very helpful.  It still seems to run into problems when setting the real and imag parts.  Your example works when real and imag are scalars, however it crashes when they are vectors (numpy arrays).  For example, running:
'
    import numpy as np
    r = np.r_[1:5]
    i = np.r_[1:5]
    c = ZMUMPS_COMPLEX(r, i)
'
crashes.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @dwfm That should be expected. The ZMUMPS_COMPLEX struct is expecting the real and imaginary parts to be double precision floating point numbers, not arrays! Is there another structure that expects a vector?

Comment: @dwfm I think I misunderstood. rhs should be an array of ZMUMPS_COMPLEX of length n or nz?

Comment: rhs should be an array of ZMUMPS_COMPLEX of length n. a should be an array of ZMUMPS_COMPLEX of length nz.